# Errores de precisión en java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Se me solicita lo siguiente
[image: Enunciado]

y esto me respondió el profesor ayer cuando lo consulte:
[image: Instrucciones]

Mi código:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

    int cantHuevos = 0;
    double porcentaje;
    double conversion;
    double total = 100000;

    System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de huevos: ");
    cantHuevos = entrada.nextInt();


    if (cantHuevos>=1 && cantHuevos<35){
       conversion = cantHuevos / 10;
       porcentaje = (total * conversion / 100);
        System.out.println("El descuento es de: "+ porcentaje);
    }
}
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono? No sé si lo estoy haciendo mal ya busqué y lo que encontré fue algo de BigDecimal.

Comment: Si debes cambiar todo a BigDecimal, es un objeto inmutable (una vez creado no puede alterarse) tiene sus métodos add, multiply, sustract, divide que te pueden ayudar a tu problema, solo cambia los double por BigDecimal BigDecimal porcentaje = new BigDecimal("0.20");

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario amigo realmente no nos han ensenado nada de BigDecimal asi que no entiendo bien como aplicarlo a mi codigo, pero al menos ya me diste una dirección hacia donde ir gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate si casteando a double cantHuevos (que es un int) se elimina el tema del redondeo (y en lugar de 10 y 100 utilizá 10.0 y 100.0 que son números con punto flotante):

```
if (cantHuevos>=1 && cantHuevos<35){
       conversion = (double)cantHuevos / 10.0);
       porcentaje = (total * conversion / 100.0);
       System.out.println("El descuento es de: "+ porcentaje);
}
```